# Netcat / nc on ec2... public/private address?

Tags: amazon-ec2, netcat

I'm trying to use nc to debug some network issues (but am sort of ending up debugging nc itself).

I have the relevant port open (to the world) in the ec2 security group.  When I run either of these commands on my ec2 server:

```
nc -n -v -v -l <private IP address> -p 4161
```

or

```
nc -n -v -v -l <public IP address> -p 4161
```

And then from any other server (on EC2 or in my local office network):

```
nc -n -v -v <public IP address> 4161
```

I get the following on the server (which then exits):

```
listening on [any] 4161 ...
invalid connection to [<private IP address>] from (UNKNOWN) [<remote IP address>] 54002
```

And on the client (which also then exits):

```
(UNKNOWN) [<public IP address>] 4161 (?) open
sent 0, rcvd 0
```

Any suggestions?

I suspect this has to do with the fact that EC2 instances have public and private IP addresses, but I'm baffled as to how to get this to work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*sigh*

Never fails.  As soon as I post a question to serverfault, a moment later I find the answer myself...

Omitting the IP address for the server netcat takes care of it:

```
nc -n -v -v -l -p 4161
```

Comment: thanks for following up. Could you explain why did this work?